# How to remove last installed driver?

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

I have a Wi-Fi adapter Realtek RTL8192CU. In Windows its speed is about 5-25 Mb/s. In Ubuntu it's only 100-200 Kb/s. So I entered the following commands as https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes said:

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11
sudo depmod -a
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

After reboot I have no connection at all. How can I undo all these commands and turn back my default driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo dkms remove 8192cu/1.11 --all
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf
```

Reboot and check:

```
sudo dkms status
```

There should be no mention of 8192cu.

If you find that your wireless is still slow, check to see if you have two conflicting drivers loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

You will probably find that *both* rtl8xxxu and rtl8192cu are loaded. Let's blacklist the least likely to succeed:

```
sudo -i 
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Any improvement? It might take a reboot.

Comment: thank you, connection is set again. lsmod | grep rtl command showed 7 lines like: rtl8xxxu, rtl8192cu, rtl_usb, rtl8192c_common, rtlwifi. I did your last commands and there is no connection again

Comment: Please try a reboot.

Comment: thank you so much. It works now. You just solved my both problems at once!